# Cannot access GeoJSON layer in react-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, react, leaflet-plugins

I am using [React Leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) to render Leaflet map and its [GeoJSON](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components#geojson) component to render polygons. I am trying to implement dragging multiple polygons.

I added [Leaflet.Path.Drag](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag) library and tried to reuse [this](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag/issues/3#issuecomment-303944144) code. I am able to get transformation matrix which is in parent's state. If I want to apply this matrix to multiple polygons with `_transform` method, it doesn't work. I think the reason is that matrix is not applied to correct layers, but I have no idea how to fix this.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-pine-5xty6?file=/src/App.js)

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, GeoJSON, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import { geoJson, latLngBounds } from "leaflet";
import "./styles.css";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

import { GeoJsonContainer } from "./GeoJsonContainer";

const objects = [
  {
    polygon: {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: [
        {
          type: "Feature",
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: "Polygon",
            coordinates: [
              [
                [-104.98569488525392, 39.63431579014969],
                [-104.98569488525392, 39.64165260123419],
                [-104.97161865234376, 39.64165260123419],
                [-104.97161865234376, 39.63431579014969]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    polygon: {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: [
        {
          type: "Feature",
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: "Polygon",
            coordinates: [
              [
                [-105.02964019775392, 39.6206315500488],
                [-105.02964019775392, 39.65685252543906],
                [-104.99067306518556, 39.65685252543906],
                [-104.99067306518556, 39.6206315500488]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const getPolygonPointFromBounds = (latLngBounds) => {
  const center = latLngBounds.getCenter();
  const latlngs = [];

  latlngs.push(latLngBounds.getSouthWest()); //bottom left
  latlngs.push({ lat: latLngBounds.getSouth(), lng: center.lng }); //bottom center
  latlngs.push(latLngBounds.getSouthEast()); //bottom right
  latlngs.push({ lat: center.lat, lng: latLngBounds.getEast() }); // center right
  latlngs.push(latLngBounds.getNorthEast()); //top right
  latlngs.push({
    lat: latLngBounds.getNorth(),
    lng: latLngBounds.getCenter().lng
  }); //top center
  latlngs.push(latLngBounds.getNorthWest()); //top left
  latlngs.push({
    lat: latLngBounds.getCenter().lat,
    lng: latLngBounds.getWest()
  }); //center left

  return latlngs;
};

export default function App() {
  const [matrix, setMatrix] = React.useState(null);

  let newBounds = [];
  let selectBoundingBox = [];

  objects.forEach((building) => {
    const polygonBounds = geoJson(building.polygon).getBounds();
    newBounds = [...newBounds, polygonBounds];
  });

  const polygonPoints = getPolygonPointFromBounds(latLngBounds(newBounds));
  const convertedData = polygonPoints.map((point) => [point.lng, point.lat]);
  convertedData.push([polygonPoints[0].lng, polygonPoints[0].lat]);
  selectBoundingBox = convertedData;

  let selectBoxData = null;

  if (selectBoundingBox) {
    selectBoxData = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: [
        {
          type: "Feature",
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: "Polygon",
            coordinates: [selectBoundingBox]
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  const handleFeature = (layer) => {
    layer.makeDraggable();
    layer.dragging.enable();

    layer.on("drag", function (e) {
      setMatrix(layer.dragging._matrix);
    });
  };

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[39.63563779557324, -104.99234676361085]} zoom={12}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {objects.map((object, i) => (
        <GeoJsonContainer data={object} key={i} matrix={matrix} />
      ))}
      <GeoJSON
        data={selectBoxData}
        style={() => ({
          color: "green",
          weight: 3,
          opacity: 0.5
        })}
        draggable={true}
        onEachFeature={(feature, layer) => handleFeature(layer)}
      ></GeoJSON>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

**GeoJsonContainer.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";

require("leaflet-path-drag");

export const GeoJsonContainer = (props) => {
  const geoJSONRef = React.useRef(null);
  const layerRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (geoJSONRef?.current?._layers) {
      console.log("mount layers", geoJSONRef.current?._layers);
    }
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (geoJSONRef?.current._layers && props.matrix) {
      console.log("transform layers", geoJSONRef.current._layers);
      const key = Object.keys(geoJSONRef.current._layers)[0];
      const geoJSONElementLayer = geoJSONRef.current._layers[key];
      if (geoJSONElementLayer) {
        console.log("geoJSONElementLayer", geoJSONElementLayer);
        console.log("layerRef.current", layerRef.current);
        geoJSONElementLayer._transform(props.matrix);
        layerRef.current._transform(props.matrix);
      }
    }
  }, [props.matrix]);

  const handleFeature = (layer) => {
    console.log("handleFeature layer", layer);
    layerRef.current = layer;
    layer.makeDraggable();
    layer.dragging.enable();
  };

  return (
    <GeoJSON
      ref={geoJSONRef}
      data={props.data.polygon}
      style={() => ({
        color: "#3388ff",
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 1
      })}
      dragging={true}
      onEachFeature={(feature, layer) => handleFeature(layer)}
    ></GeoJSON>
  );
};
```

Comment: "If I want to apply this matrix to multiple polygons with _transform method, it doesn't work" - you mean you want to drag the polygons together at once, as a group?

Comment: @SethLutske yes, exactly

Comment: @Matt have you simply thought about using [turf.js transformTranslate](https://turfjs.org/docs/#transformTranslate), you could probably get the values of direction and distance using [turf.js centroid](https://turfjs.org/docs/#centroid) on the polygon at `dragstart` and `dragend` and using [turf.js distance](https://turfjs.org/docs/#distance) and [turf.js bearing](https://turfjs.org/docs/#bearing)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try this. I don't have an issue with getting transformation values. The issue is that GeoJSON layers don't transform. I think there is something wrong with `react-leaflet` component.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65857656/cannot-access-geojson-layer-in-react-leaflet